# fatal: Not a git repository: wrong repo path

Tags: git

For some reason my git repo path got screwed up
When I am trying to do any git command, e.g. git status I am getting the following error

```
fatal: Not a git repository: <dir>/C:\cygwin\home\<project>\.git\modules\<name of module>
```

for some reason there is a dir in front of the C:\ path. I tried to look in the .git directory, and in config but everything seems to be correct there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `.git folder`, one level up and then try to run `git log`, to see if your commits are shown and everything works.

Comment: I can do git log without moving this directory, and I can see commits.

Comment: git pull on the other hand results in the same error

Comment: is there a way to remove the <dir> part in front of the C:/ path?